# Cannot Read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml and content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I'am a beginner in developing android studio project. Here I have a problem and wish if anybody can show me whats wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml, i have tried so many solutions but still cant fix my problem

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.acer.pregnancyislamicpractices"
    android:versoinCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SurahZikir">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SURAHZIKIR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Nama">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NAMA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.acer.pregnancyislamicpractices.Lelaki">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LELAKI" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Perempuan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PEREMPUAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Surah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SURAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ZikirDoa">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ZIKIRDOA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Keputusan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.KEPUTUSAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Fatihah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FATIHAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Baqarah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BAQARAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Kursi">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.KURSI" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Imranlapan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IMRANLAPAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Araaf">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ARAAF" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Furqan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FURQAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Ibrahim">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IBRAHIM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Imran">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IMRAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Nahl">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NAHL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Sajdah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SAJDAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Yasin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.YASIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Pah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Mypim">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MYPIM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Pnz">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PNZ" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Lah">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LAH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Lin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Lqz">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LQZ" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".DataListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATALISTACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHERT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DataKesihatanActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATAKESIHATANACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHERT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Comment: please help me, i already try so many solution but still not okay :'(

Comment: cannot read package name means?

Comment: i also not understand why @user4057066 because when i try to run my project ,message Gradle Build showing two error that saying Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\acer\AndroidStudioProjects\PregnancyIslamicApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml and Error:Content is not allowed in trailing section.

Comment: I suggest to check your drawables (selector.xml something like this) If you are using any. There is some mistake in that i think..!!

Comment: @AkrinaAkram Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your build.gradle file.

The Error messages seems gradle cannot find AndroidManifest.xml file in which it should be placed.

If AndroidManifest.xml file's content is Ok, you should confirm the AndroidManifest file is at the folder in directory which gradle expect to find.

Comment: I never thought that AndroidManifest file was in the wrong folder. I imported  a library module and manifest file was located at the root folder of the library module but gradle expected it to be inside the main folder. `library/src/main`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line in the Manifest

```
android:versoinCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
```

This should be in `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Why is it so damn hard to get the right answer! Here I stumble upon after 24 hours. Merciless android.

Answer (score 0):

actually the answer was there all the time.

change this line (4th line in your manifest) -

```
android:versoinCode
```

to be

```
android:versionCode
```

in addition, there can be only 1 MAIN intent-filter activity. remove all the

```
<intent-filter> ... </intent-filter>
```

from all your activities except .SPLASH activity (the first one)